# Office365 calendar: Retrieves information about the availability of a set of users during a specified time period

Tags: javascript, outlook, office365, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to retrieves information about the availability of a set of users during a specified time period with [Microsoft graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph) API from users Office365 Outlook calendars? I need to get information about users busy periods and display it.

Like in [ExchangeService.GetUserAvailability](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.exchangeservice.getuseravailability(v=exchg.80).aspx) method in Microsoft Exchange WebServices.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an exact mirror to `GetUserAvailability` in Microsoft Graph API but similar functionality is supported via the [/findMeetingTimes](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_findmeetingtimes) method.

Comment: findMeetingTimes method did not help in my case. I want to get information about users busy periods to display. I added note about it to question.